# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "create": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm getting a rather strange syntax error in my `schema.sql` file.

The error is as follows:

> File "/Users/user/Documents/GitProjects/FlaskApp/flaskr/db.py", line
>   88, in init_db_command
>       init_db() File "/Users/user/Documents/GitProjects/FlaskApp/flaskr/db.py", line 80, in
>   init_db
>       db.executescript(f.read().decode("utf-8")) sqlite3.OperationalError: near "create": syntax error

My schema looks like this:

```
drop table if exists post;
drop table if exists post_user;

create table post_user (
    user_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    email text unique not null,
    username text unique not null,
    password text not null
);

create table post (
    post_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    author_id integer not null,
    create timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
    title text not null,
    body text not null,
    foreign key (author_id) references post_user (user_id)
);
```

And my python looks like this:

```
def init_db():
    db = get_db()
    with current_app.open_resource("schema.sql") as f:
        db.executescript(f.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

And finally the directory:

```
root
 |--db.py
 |--schema.sql
instance
 |-- project.sqlite
```

I'm using flask and sqlite3.
And my troubleshooting steps have been the following:

1) Remove everything except the first line (this works)

2) Removed everything except the first two lines (this doesn't)

3) Remove the `./instance/project.sqlite` file

4) Use an online validator
    This was especially interesting because this found that each individual command works.
    But as soon as I string two back-to-back it said the commands were invalid.

5) Double checked the sqlite documentation on dropping tables

6) Even went so far as to ensure my `.vimrc` was set to `utf-8`

I'm sure I've missed something small here but nothing seems to be working.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I did? It's in the second block there. It's the thing resulting in the error. And it's what's being called by my python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely want `create timestamp` column to be something like `create_timestamp` to avoid clashing with sql keywords.

Comment: This was the issue. I changed the line `created TIMESTAMP...` to `create timestamp` by accident. Thank you!

Comment: Solved, in my case I was creating a table ORDER, renamed it to ORDERS and that fixed it